# PHP / MySQL: recursive array / recursive SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, recursion

### EXPLAIN

Let's say we have this `transaction` table :

```
+----+-------------+--------+----------------+----------------+---------------------+
| id | id_customer | amount | id_where_trans | id_money_from  |        date_trans   |
+----+-------------+--------+----------------+----------------+---------------------+
|  1 |          10 |     10 |            100 | NULL           | 2015-07-20 10:20:30 |
|  2 |          10 |     -2 |            100 | NULL           | 2015-07-21 09:10:11 |
|  3 |          10 |      7 |            120 | NULL           | 2015-07-24 18:22:25 |
|  4 |          10 |    -11 |            120 | here the magic | 2015-07-24 18:22:26 |
+----+-------------+--------+----------------+----------------+---------------------+
```

Read this in "human" language:

id 1 => Customer Alessandro (id_customer 10) charge 10€ on his account in shop A (id_where trans = 100)

id 2 => Customer Alessandro spent 2€ on Shop A

id 3 => Customer Alessandro charge 7€ on his account in shop **B**

id 4 => Customer ALessandro spend 11€ in shop B.

At the end of period (month, for example), Shop B need to receive 8€ (+10-2) from another shop, in our example shop A.

/end of human read.

You imagine that insert is a simple (for id 4, for example):

```
INSERT INTO transaction (id_customer, amount, id_where_trans, date) VALUES (10,-11,120,2015-07-24 18:22:26)
```

### GOAL

My goal is set - during the insert, and if possible / simpler via PHP - the SQL splitted in two or more SELECT:

```
INSERT INTO transaction (id_customer, amount, id_where_trans, id_money_from, date) VALUES (10,-8,120,100,2015-07-24 18:22:26)

INSERT INTO transaction (id_customer, amount, id_where_trans, id_money_from, date) VALUES (10,-3,120,NULL,2015-07-24 18:22:27)



    +----+-------------+--------+----------------+------------+---------------------+
| id | id_customer | amount | id_where_trans | id_money_from |        date         |
+----+-------------+--------+----------------+------------+---------------------+
|  1 |          10 |     10 |            100 | NULL       | 2015-07-20 10:20:30 |
|  2 |          10 |     -2 |            100 | NULL       | 2015-07-21 09:10:11 |
|  3 |          10 |      7 |            120 | NULL       | 2015-07-24 18:22:25 |
|  4 |          10 |     -8 |            120 | 100        | 2015-07-24 18:22:26 |
|  5 |          10 |     -3 |            120 | NULL       | 2015-07-24 18:22:27 |
+----+-------------+--------+----------------+------------+---------------------+
```

If I can get a table with that informations, I can run a query that make my final job correctly.

Basically, I need to calculate the id_shop where money are taken for discharge (in this case, -8 from 100, that made previous charge, and so is NOT NULL, and -3 from 120,itself, THIS IS NULL).

**Please note that FIRST I consume / discharge the previous charge (id 4 now has id_money_from 100), AFTER I will consume / discharge others amounts (id 5 in effect is NULL, because that -3 has taken from id 3)**

### ASSUMPTION / MANDATARY

1) id are INCREMENTAL, no concurrency. Date are INCREMENTAL, date of id 4 is >= of id 3 and so on.

2) If amount of last recharge is made from same id where transaction is done (see id 1 and id 2) insert NULL (I need mandatary NULL)

3) First charge made, first need to be zero-ed, and so on.

### MY LOGIC / PSEUDOCODE

1) If a transaction is negative, make a recursive getting LAST positive charge which, summed to the negative susequential, is not zero.

getted this charge, if id_where_trans==id_money_from we need insert, simply insert, with NULL

```
INSERT INTO transaction (id_customer, amount, id_where_trans, id_money_from, date) VALUES (10,-2,120,NULL,2015-07-24 18:22:26)
```

**Recursive start here**

*If this amount is <= of last recharge, walking in database and split negative in **two or more** id_where_trans (problaby in real scenario this will be impossible, but I need to think that amount from discharge (id_money_from) could be splitted by 2, 3, x id_where_trans). For example, if SHOP A charge +1, Shop B charge +1, Shop C charge +1 and SHOP D DISCHARGE -3, we need to insert 3 different rows.*

```
$amount_to_discharge = x;

$last_positive = $query->("SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE "); // make the SUB-SUM

if ($last_positive['amount'] >= $amount_to_discharge) {
    $query->("INSERT INTO......");
} else {
   // start recursive
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM AMOUNT WHERE amount > 0 AND id < $last_positive['id']";
   $new_search = $query->sql($sql);
   // how implement correctly that recursive?

}
```

Thank you guy. Let me know if you need others explain!

Comment: Many accounting systems like this handle end-of-month settlements with extra end-of-month transactions. They employ a end-of-month settlement job that runs in the first hours or days after the end of the month. But your specification seems to call for the settlement transaction to occur before, in time and in sequence, the final customer transaction of the month.  Is that mandatory?  How can you do that?

Comment: @OllieJones sorry, I did not understand you...